# What is the best way in JDBC to insert blob into oracle?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, blob

I have a java code that should insert byte-array to Oracle database into blob column.
The function signature is:

```
void loadBlob(Connection connection, byte[] byteData, PreparedStatement ps) {...}
```

The byte-array is passed as parameter(no need to read it from any source/stream).

The ps was created using:

```
connection.prepareStatement("insert into mytable values(?)")
```

The mytable script is : `create table mytable (myblob blob)`

### There are many ways to load blob:

1. Using standard jdbc Blob object

```
Blob blob = connection.createBlob();
blob.setBytes(1, byteData);
ps.setBlob(1, blob);
ps.execute();
blob.free();
```

2. Using oracle's specific object

```
Blob blob = BLOB.createTemporary(connection, false, BLOB.DURATION_SESSION);
blob.setBytes(1, byteData);
ps.setBlob(1, blob);
ps.execute();
blob.free();
```

3. Using oracle's database function hextoraw

```
PreparedStatement ps2 = connection.prepareStatement("insert into mytable values (hextoraw(?))")
//convert the byte array to hexadecimal digits - the implementation is skipped to avoid de-focus from the main issue
String hexaDigits = convertByteArrayToHexaDigits(byteData);
ps2.setString(1, hexaDigits);
ps2.execute();
```

### The Question

What are the advantages/disadvantages for the above ways? 
Are there any other better ways?

Answer (score 1):

Your first and second example appear to be identical to me:

```
blob.setBytes(1, byteData);
ps.setBlob(1, blob);
ps.execute();
blob.free();
```

I would probably choose this method over your third example.  The reason for this is that the third example involves invoking an Oracle function `hextoraw`.  This would probably incur an extra overhead during the insert, and so might not perform as well as options 1 or 2.

Comment: There was an error in formatting, which caused first line to disappear. I have fixed it. Now the examples 1 and 2 are different.

Answer (score 1):

Best way I know:

`ps.setBytes( 1, byteData );`

HTH
Loïc

Comment: You can insert up to 2GB of data using this method.